Discrete to continuous quantum operator
Let's say that we have a discrete lattice with $N$ sites. Let's label the site by the index $i$.
Let's say that we have the operators $a_i$ and $a_i^\dagger$ which correspond to the creation and annihilation of magnons. We have
$$\hat{N}=\sum_i a_i^\dagger a_i,$$
where $\hat{N}$ is the number operator.
Let's say we want to use a continuum limit for the Hamiltonian (rather than a discrete sum. The Hamiltonian consists of terms that are quadratic in these operators) by using continuous creation/annihilation operators $\phi^\dagger(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ respectively, which also satisfy the commutation relations for bosons. Then, we need to make the following substitutions:
$$a_i^\dagger \to \sqrt{a} \phi^\dagger(x),$$
$$a_i \to \sqrt{a} \phi(x),$$
where the $\sqrt{a}$ is a result of the normalization by conserving the total particle number:
$$\hat{N}=\sum_i a_i^\dagger a_i = \int dx \phi^\dagger(x)\phi(x).$$
I still don't understand this normalization factor of $\sqrt{a}$. How does the conservation of total particle number when moving from sum to integral exactly require this normalization factor of $\sqrt{a}$? It still doesn't make quite sense to me, even with the above explanation.
$a$ is the lattice constant/spacing here. Furthermore, we have:
$\phi(x+a) \approx \phi(x) + a\frac{d\phi}{dx}$

What is $\sqrt a$ supposed to mean? I mean it cannot be any constant, no? Do you have a reference for all of this?

These were taken from lecture notes so I don't have a reference, I added all the necessary context available to me, including what is meant with $a$.

Can you ask your lecturer? Anyway: When going from discrete sums to integrals (for a finite volume), pre-factors indeed occur.

I assume that $a$ is meant to be the lattice spacing, although I might suggest using if different symbol from the one you use for the creation/annihilation operators

I think you're right, I will add it to the post.

Related question.

If $x= na$ then write $\sqrt a\phi(na)= a_n$ etc,
$$ 
\sum_n a^\dagger_n a_n \sim  \int \phi^\dagger (na) \phi(na) adn=
\int \phi^\dagger( x) \phi(x) dx,
$$
the "$\sim$" being the usual approximation of a sum of slowly varying things by an integral.

But how do you go from $\sum_n a_n^\dagger a_n$ to $\int \phi^\dagger(na) \phi(na) adn$? This approximation doesn't make sense to me and where it comes from.

A continuum limit means that all   momenta are small compared to $a^{-1}$, so that the matrix elements of the $a_n$ are slowly varying functions of $n$. This is why the sum can be approximated by the integral.

But it doesn't make sense to write $x = na$ right? Because $x$ is supposed to be a continuous parameter but $na$ is discrete since $n$ is an integer and $a$ a fixed constant.

@Stallmp Yes, $x$ is discrete, but the point is that for $a\to 0$, its possible values become closer and closer, and the approximation then is to treat it as a continuous variable (and the sum as an integral).

Okay I get it now. It was just confusing since there were many steps skipped, but the trick is to convert the variable from $n$ to $x$ in the sum, then multiplying by $a/a$ where $\Delta x = a$, letting $a \to 0$ and then converting the sum to an integral. Then finally defining the $\phi$ variable to cancel the $1/a$ factor outside the integral.
